# Не могу установить python-gi

Tags: python, apt-get, зависимости

ОС: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

После установки сделал следующее (чтобы заменить дефолтный python 2.7 на python 3.5):

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
```

Позже появилась проблема с обновлением системы, пакетов и программ. Выглядит это так:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово

Расчёт обновлений… Готово обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено. не установлено до конца или удалено 6 пакетов. После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B. Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y Настраивается пакет python-gi (3.20.0-0ubuntu1) … Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \   File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gi (--configure):  подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1 dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет alacarte:  alacarte зависит от python-gi (>= 3.0), однако:   Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета alacarte (--configure):  проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным Настраивается пакет python-cairo (1.8.8-2) … Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \   File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-cairo (--configure):  подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1 dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python-gi-cairo:  python-gi-cairo зависит от python-gi (= 3.20.0-0ubuntu1), однако:   Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.  python-gi-cairo зависит от python-cairo, однако:   Пакет python-cairo пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gi-cairo (--configure):  проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным Настраивается пакет python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) … Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \   File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gobject-2 (--configure):  подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1 Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python-gobject:  python-gobject зависит от python-gi (>= 3.20.0-0ubuntu1), однако:   Пакет python-gi пока не настроен.  python-gobject зависит от python-gobject-2, однако: Пакет python-gobject-2 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python-gobject (--configure):  проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным Отчёты apport не записаны, так достигнут MaxReports
                                                   Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) … При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:  python-gi  alacarte  python-cairo  python-gi-cairo  python-gobject-2  python-gobject E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Помогите пож-та разобраться.

Comment: *"После установки сделал следующее (чтобы заменить дефолтный python 2.7 на python 3.5)"* — не меняйте **системный** python (такие вещи как apt-get его могут использовать), это может сломать систему. Для себя (пользователя) можно любые версии, хоть несколько Python реализаций одновременно использовать (pypy, jython)—хоть руками ~/bin/python ссылку создайте (если ~/bin в $PATH) или с помощью инструментов типа conda, pythonz можно управлять версиями python для пользователя.

Comment: Вопрос решен переустановкой системы.

Ссылка на возможное решение: http://askubuntu.com/questions/854468/cannot-install-python-gi/854471?noredirect=1#comment1314821_854471